# Use coordinate vectors to decide or not the given set is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I find the coordinate vectors of this matrix set?
$$\left[ 
\begin{matrix} 
1&2& \\ 
-1&0\end{matrix}\right]$$
$$\left[ 
\begin{matrix} 
0&-1& \\ 
1&1\end{matrix}\right]$$
$$\left[ 
\begin{matrix} 
1&0& \\ 
1&2\end{matrix}\right]$$

in $$M_2,_2$$

I have a feeling that the coordinate vectors are just $\{(1,2,-1,0), (0,-1,1,1),(1,0,1,2)\}$.

Do correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no unique answer to your question. The vector space $$M_{2x2}$$ is isomorphic to $$R^{4}$$, so if you pick the standard base, your answer is correct. If you picked another base, the answer would’ve been different.